Can someone please help or give advice?
My name is Ana and Spanish is my 1st language.
I was 2yrs old when I came to USA.
I put so much effort to learn English but as you can see I struggle putting sentences together. It’s extremely difficult to write down and explain what I’m thinking. I can spend 2 hours in 1 paragraph trying to say what I’m thinking. I end up changing removing words to avoid using a sentence as a result I end up deleting the whole thing. I am left with all kinds of emotion at the end mostly anger & frustration for doing it to myself. I have horrible anxiety resulting in panic attacks. I’m all kinds of messed up.
I am 35 years old I’ve searched online for tips lessons on grammar. I don’t even know if grammar is  what I struggle with.
I know it’s too much I apologize. Can someone please give any advice or help?
Anything helps.
“Normally it would have taken 3-4 hours to write this down different ways just to give up & delete everything. I have to post it as is if I want help. I apologize again for the anxiety I’m giving just by reading this”
-Ana

If you still live in the US, try to get out more and talk to more people in English. It's almost impossible to learn a language from books. Almost every single native Anglophone learned English by listening and talking, not by reading and writing. When you're talking, don't waste time worrying about whether your grammar is correct - just concentrate on being understood. Also don't waste time trying to think of the exact word for what you want to refer to. Use lots of simple words to describe it, and maybe remember when the other person tells you what it is.

Being too self conscious and being afraid that you would make a mistake prevents you from conversing with others.
When a family moves to a new location, it's frequently the case that the kids pick up the language more quickly than the adults do since they don't mind making mistakes.

Welcome! First, good job working to improve, that takes bravery and strength. This particular site is not the best place for general advice questions like this one. Maybe look for forums or other advice-focused sites? On this site, you can ask specific questions about the English language (like if you're confused about a specific word, how to say something specific, or how to understand something you have heard or seen).

That said, here are some resources that you might find helpful:


Have you looked in your area for ELL groups for adults? Local libraries often have them, or sometimes they are hosted through community colleges or at local schools. Everyone there is learning and practicing together, so there is no need to feel embarrassed if you make mistakes or have difficulty thinking of the words you want.


It also sounds like you might benefit from someone to talk to about this. Maybe consider looking in your area for a Spanish-speaking therapist. They can help you work through the anxiety


